# Large difference in battery discharge, when Nexus 7 is on and off

Tags: battery, nexus-7, charging

My father got a brand new Google Nexus 7 II (2013) LTE tablet few weeks ago. Ever since first use, he was complying about battery discharge rate. Few days ago, I did some measures and I'm quite shocked:

1. When battery was charged up to approximately *60-70% at 10 pm* and *tablet was turned completely off*, battery turned out to be *completely exhausted* (0% charge) at *6 am* next day. So, **it lost 60% / 8h**.
2. When battery was charged up to *100% at 10 pm on Thursday* (!) and *tablet was left on*, but not used at all (screen dimmed, airplane mode, tablet lying on shelf), battery turned out to have *90% charge level* on *Sunday morning* (!). So, **it lost 10% / 60h (2,5 days)** (!!!).

How it is possible, that mobile device, equipped with nearly newest Android, has so enormous differences in battery drainage, when it is turned on, but unused, versus it is turned off completely? This is **something completely unbelievable** (I wouldn't believed if, if I hadn't seen this for my own eyes)! We have battery discharge of **7,5% per hour in first case versus 0.16% per hour in second case**. That is **45 times slower**!

Is this normal (I haven't observed something like that on any other of my mobile devices, including two years older Google Nexus phone) or does it suggests battery / tablet malfuction?

Comment: At the very moment of writing this (Wenesday, 9:30 GMT) tablet has 45% of battery charge, though, it wasn't charged since previous Thursday! It seems, that it is going to manage until tomorrow evening, without charging, which will make it operable for **entire week** on one charging. While (when constantly being turned on), it wasn't able to "survive" one entire day. I'm devastated with the differences in battery consumption, when this device is on and off. What can drain battery so badly, when device is permanently turned off?

Comment: @beeshyams I have no idea why. The only opinion, that I found, was Area 51-like, that when tablet is switch off, it only pretends to be switched off, but still sends data to Google. Since it does this silently, it consumes a lot of energy. Much more than when sending these data officially (when turned on). I know, that this explanation sounds like a maniac blable, but the fact remains, that my Nexus can spend up to entire week on single charge, when turned on all the time, while dies completely, from full charge to 0% during single night, when turned off.

Comment: @beeshyams Sorry, same on this side. I have also no experience using _logcat_ or similar tools. Plus, I'm not using that Nexus anymore, so I guess, that ends discussion. Unfortunately, without a conclusion.